# How to calculate tf-idf for a list of dict?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a list of texts where each text is stored as a dict with its id as key and texts data as its value. How can I calculate [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) for this data. E.g.:

```
{1: 'This is cat', 2: 'Is this the first document?', 3: 'And the third one.'}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your dictionary into a list of the strings by :

```
    X_all = list(d.values())
```

Build the tfIDFVectoriser function as :

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

    tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None,
    strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
    ngram_range=(1,2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1,
    stop_words = 'english')
```

and then you can build your model as :

```
    X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)
```

where X_all is the list of text documents.